# Traversing a DOM object to find specific element

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a DOM object that has the following structure:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/AY735S2.png]

I've tried the following to get the element I need, but it returns an error:

```
file[0].previewElement.find('.dz-progress');
```

The error I get:

```
file[0].previewElement.find is not a function
```

How do I traverse the HTML of this DOM object?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wrap JavaScript code with jQuery to use jQuery methods like this:

```
$(file[0].previewElement).find('.dz-progress');
```

Comment: @user4703663 Have to wait 10 minutes.

Answer (score 3):

It has to be wrapped

```
$(file[0].previewElement).find('.dz-progress');
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use only javascript for that too.

```
file[0].previewElement.querySelectorAll('.dz-progress');
```